# Testing issues with Material UI component and difficulties in changing screen width for testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am working on a React pet-project that uses Material UI, and I am facing issues while testing my Header component. I am attempting to test the component's behavior at various screen widths because ,for example, certain elements of the header should only be visible on smaller screens. However,  when I test the component , it does not render as expected.

I understand that the default screen width set by Jest is 1024px, which means that the burger button should not be visible during testing,but the burger button remains visible.

```
 /Header.tsx

export default function Header() {
const [open, setState] = useState(false);

const toggleDrawer = (open: boolean) => () => {
setState(open);
};

return (
<AppBar position='static' sx={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
  <Toolbar sx={{ minHeight: { xs: '56px' } }}>
    <Link href='/' sx={{ marginRight: '20px' }}>
      <Box component='img' sx={{ width: '135px' }} alt='Logo' src={logo} />
    </Link>
    <Box
      component='nav'
      sx={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'flex' },
        flex: '1 1 auto'
      }}>
      <List sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        {pageLinks.map((item: Page) => (
          <ListItem key={item.page}>
            <Link
              sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flex: '0 0 auto',
                textDecoration: 'none',
                color: 'primary.contrastText'
              }}>
              {item.page}
            </Link>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: { xs: '1 1 auto', sm: '0 0 0' },
        justifyContent: { xs: 'end' },
        alignItems: 'center',
        gap: { md: '10px' }
      }}>
      <IconButton>
        <SearchIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton component='a' sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'inline-flex' } }}>
        <PersonOutlineOutlinedIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'inline-flex' } }}>
        <WbSunnyOutlinedIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
    <Box sx={{ display: { sm: 'none' }, marginLeft: '15px' }}>
      <IconButton aria-label='click to open drawer' onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}>
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
    <Drawer anchor='right' open={open} onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}>
      <Box sx={{ p: 2, height: 1 }}>
        <IconButton sx={{ mb: 2 }} onClick={toggleDrawer(false)}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Divider />
        <Box>
          {pageLinks.map((el: Page) => (
            <ListItem key={el.page}>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon sx={{ minWidth: '40px' }}>
                  <el.icon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText>
                  <Link sx={{ color: 'primary.contrastText', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                    {el.page}
                  </Link>
                </ListItemText>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
          <Divider />
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon sx={{ minWidth: '40px' }}>
                <AccountCircleOutlinedIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText>Account</ListItemText>
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <Switch />
            Dark Mode
          </ListItem>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Drawer>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
);
}


/Header.test.tsx 

it('Header should hide the burger button when screen width is over 600px', () => {
render(<Header />);
const burgerButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /click to open drawer/i });
expect(burgerButton).not.toBeVisible();
});
```

Test failed with this error -

```
expect(element).not.toBeVisible()

Received element is visible:
  <button aria-label="click to open drawer" class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-78trlr-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root" tabindex="0" type="button" />
```

I have a follow-up question that is related to this issue. Even after manually setting the screen width using the code, for example

```
global.innerWidth = 500; 
global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

the component still renders the same way without any changes.

I would be really grateful for any help I can get.

Comment: If your using MUI, I suggest using [useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/), rather than an external javascript library. It makes things much more simple than you're what your currently attempting.